# Which event is fired after uploading a new version of File in chatter?

Tags: chatter, chatter-file, chatter-groups

Actually I have to write a a code after uploading a new version to generate a new alert for User(customized alert, not feed post). So, anyone knows which event is triggered after uploading a new version of File in chatter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you building your own chatter? I don't think you can capture anything via standard UI?

Comment: Customized UI and all the functionality is customized. I want to generate a notification(FB/stack overflow style) notification alert after New Version of File is uploaded.

Comment: Hey, You can use a ContentVersion trigger and write your notification in this trigger.

Comment: I tried with Content version, it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

**It's the ContentDocument's update event.**

Basically, ContentVersion stores information about the other details such as Title, Description. However the original content will be modified at ContentDocument object only.